# Error with connection() to Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I encountered some errors connecting to Hibernate. This gives an error:

```
public static void makeReport(String type, Map<String, Object> param)  throws JRException, IOException{
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
    **Connection con = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession().connection();**error here
    String outputFileName = "Hóa đơn ";
    JRAbstractExporter exporter = null;

    if(type == "7" || type == "8" || type == "9"){
        if(type==REPORT_BY_MONTH){
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("data\\Thống kê theo tháng.jasper", param, con);
        outputFileName += "thống kê theo tháng " + param.get("@Month") + "-" + param.get("@Year") +  ".xlsx";;
}
```

[You can find the code project here](https://mega.co.nz/#!UV4SHJqI!CPLcmtb-Wrljh5PU2M_8oY8hBJz5HmwED-_9jan076E).

Comment: Could you provide the errors that you are getting and perhaps point to what you have done as far as configuring Hibernate? It is difficult to answer this question without knowing what the symptoms are.

Comment: These comparisons are all wrong, `type == "7" || type == "8" || type == "9"` and I am quite sure you know precisely why (use the `equals()` method which is overridden in the `String` class). The correction is entirely left to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to generated a JSper report for that you might need JDBC conventional Connection Object.

Are you trying to get JDBC `Connection` object you use this below code.

```
 public void doWorkOnConnection(Session session) {
session.doWork(new Work() {
  public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
  //use the connection here...
      }
    });
   }
```

if you are looing for a Connection object just to interact with DB in hibernate way.

```
 Session session - HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();//or   getSession()
```

Session object here is kind of wrapper class for JDBC conncetion object. you can sue `Session` object as `Connection` convention object JDBC procedure.

Comment: you can teamviewer help me.
id : 474 071 962
pass: 3832

Comment: :) Sorry I could not make it now.. As i am in office. What is the error you are getting please explain in your question. Are you still facing the same error even after trying that above code ?